# qmake: custom step for each make call

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I can easily edit Makefile to add custom step. For example, I have a line:

```
first: release
```

If I change it to

```
first: pre-build release
```

Then I'll be able to place some operations after "pre-build:" label.

The question is how to write corresponding instruction to .pro file, to force **qmake** tool generate required lines in Makefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom target to your resulting `Makefile` using `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS` variable, kind of that:

```
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += beforebuild
beforebuild.commands = echo Hello world!
beforebuild.CONFIG = phony
```

However, you **cannot** put this target onto `first: all` line, unless you've patched `qmake`'s source code (consider the following snippet from `makefile.cpp`: `t << "first: " << targets.first()->target << endl`).

In principle, it's possible to induce some dependency between `all` (or `release` / `debug`) and your `beforebuild` target, so `beforebuild` would still get executed by `make` automatically, as described in [this article](http://blog.mgsxx.com/?p=2180) (Russian language). Yet the resulting solution seems to me too ugly and error-prone.

I think that simply executing `make beforebuild first` (probably, using a shell script) is much easier. Unless you're using Qt Creator, in this case you should try the recipe from the link above.

Comment: I agree we shouldn't patch qmake in this case. Phony extra target and shell script works good. In my simple case shell script may help without using phony as well, however in general (to keep all paths and build variables in single place) it is better to use extra target, thank you!